# Extracting frames from image in C#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I`ve seen some stackover flow on how to do this but i cant get it to work for myself in visual studio.

What is wrong with code? I have downloaded FFMpeg and im using it as reference. yet, I get the error

> "Could not load file or assembly Aforge.Video.FFMPEG. dll or one of
>   its dependencies"

Here is the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AForge;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.FFMPEG;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // create instance of video reader
        VideoFileReader reader = new VideoFileReader( );
        // open video file
        reader.Open( "test.avi" );
        // read 100 video frames out of it
        for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
        {
        Bitmap videoFrame = reader.ReadVideoFrame( );

        videoFrame.Save(i + ".bmp");

        // dispose the frame when it is no longer required
        videoFrame.Dispose( );
        }
        reader.Close( );
    }
} 
}
```

The program stop when i click the button and comes with an error.

Comment: Did you check if the `dll` file is actually within the project folder?

Comment: I right clicked on reference added Aforge.Video and Aforge.Video.FFMPEG.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `dll` might have been moved / deleted (or) probably not checked-in. Usually the best practice is to add them in a library folder (say `lib` or `bin`) within your project. So when you check-in your stuff, all the library files get checked in too, and your references are intact.

Since the `dll` seems to be external, I'm hoping you browsed to it and added the reference.

Can you copy the `dll` file (preferably within a `lib` folder) within your project and then add the reference again?

It looks like Visual Studio added the reference but it's not able to find the file.

I'm guessing doing this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check the way you build your project as well. Some DLLs may only work under x86 or x64 build configuration. Maybe not the parent dll directly but the references it uses internally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to your bin folder the dlls from AForge.NET\Framework\Externals\ffmpeg and make sure you're running 32 bit (project properties -> debug -> platform -> x86